# Proxy Authentication Required .NET Application

Tags: proxy, authentication, .net, internet-explorer

Here's what I've got setup:

- Windows Service Account with internet access
- A .NET application which allows setting the proxy settings

  - Host
  - Port
  - Username
  - Password

When running this application the proxy server logs are showing that the credentials are being passed to the proxy server and the proxy server is allowing the traffic. However after some time under heavy load the application stops sending the credentials and therefore the proxy server returns an error.

Then, if I log onto the server where the .NET process is running and run Internet Explorer as the service account and navigate to the URL that the .NET process is trying to access and then restart the process it starts sending the credentials again.

This has happened with two different applications - Visual Studio Load Testing and also New Relic Agent.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? It looks like it only is during heavy load (or lots of request to the proxy server) that it stops sending the credentials.